# PHP Regex: Matching "Space" if only within delimiter

Tags: php, regex

I need to match only "spaces" that appear within delimiter [  ] so i can change the space with $.

Here is the text:

> [Edit the] Expression & [Text to see matches]. Roll [over matches or
> the] expression for details. Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. [Save
> Favorites and Share expressions with friends] or the Community.
> Explore your results with Tools. [A full Reference and Help is
> available in the Library or watch the video Tutorial].

Here is my regex pattern:

```
$pattern = preg_replace('/(?!\[[a-z]+)( )(?=[a-z]+\])/','$',$newString);
```

I use [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) to test my pattern. The output from that pattern look like this:

[image: regexr]

How do i matches only "spaces" that appear within delimiter [  ] Thank you.

Comment: Something like [`(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^]\s]*\K\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/wPzTo8/1) ([PHP demo](http://ideone.com/bSjEKn))?

Comment: yes for sure thanks :)

Comment: The answer you've taken doesn't care about closure. Assume you don't care either ? A better / quicker solution is to match `\[(.+?)\]` then use a callback to replace spaces in $1.

Comment: @sln i just need to match space that appear within delimiter [] and then replace the space with $ symbol. so if there is a text  "[Text to see matches]" it replaced by [Text$to$see$matches]. Thank you, as assumed... i need `\[(.+?)\]` too in other case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^]\s]*\K\s+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPzTo8/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)` - the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) the `[` symbol
- `[^]\s]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]` and whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator omitting all text matched so far in the current iteration
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/bSjEKn):

```
$str = '[Edit the] Expression & [Text to see matches]. Roll [over matches or the] expression for details. Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. [Save Favorites and Share expressions with friends] or the Community. Explore your results with Tools. [A full Reference and Help is available in the Library or watch the video Tutorial].';
$result = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^]\s]*\K\s+~', '$', $str);
echo $result;
```

Another approach: match `[...]` substrings (with the `\[[^][]+]` pattern) and only replace whitespace inside the matches with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~\[[^][]+]~', function ($m) {
    return preg_replace('~\s+~', '$', $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

See [another PHP demo](http://ideone.com/oMJ8Rh).